# Nonlinear Second Order ODE: Minimum Relaxation (smallest possible modification)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential

Consider the following nonlinear second order ordinary differential equation:

$$\ddot y + p(t,y)\dot y + q(t,y)y = 0 $$

Is the above equation autonomous? I would say no, due to the dependence on t

Is the above equation homogeneous? I would say yes, due to the RHS

Suppose two functions $y = \phi _1(t) $ and $ y = \phi _2(t) $ solve the ODE individually. Is $y = a_1\phi _1(t) + a_2\phi _2(t) $ where $a_1$ and $a_2$ are scalar constants, also a solution? I would say no based on the principle of superposition

Now here is my question:

**Write the minimum relaxation (smallest possible modification) to the ODE such that $y = a_1\phi _t(t)$ is also a solution of the relaxed form.**

Isn't the above a trick question? The solution is simply multiplying a given solution by a constant and the original ODE is homogeneous

Any clarification would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It's not linear, so you're not guaranteed that a constant times a solution is also a solution. $p$ and $q$ mess that up. So, I would say it's not a trick question.

Comment: Changing $p(t,y)$ to $p(t)$ and $q(t,y)$ to $q(t)$ would work, by making the equation linear. But I'm not sure that's the smallest possible modification. I wonder if you add some other constraint on $p$ and $q,$ whether you could get it to work. Maybe homogeneity?